# Finding sub and parent elements in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have to loop through several webpages and click on a certain button.  I'm reasonably certain that for each webpage the absolute xpath of the element that I need to click on will be

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/ol[1]/li[2]/a[1]
```

However, sometimes I will need to click on only one element in the webpage sometimes up to three or four, but I don't know how many elements there will be.  Further, it might not be the case that for each webapage the absolute xpath will be as exactly as I have described. I need a more reliable way to find the xpaths that I'm searching for.  I was hoping that I could get all of the subelements of a certain element.  I would think that the parent element of the above object would be:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/ol[1]
```

But it's not.  When I input:

```
from selenium import driver
driver.get(url)
t = driver.switch_to.active_element
v = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/ol[1]"
obj = t.find_elements(By.XPATH, v)
```

I get an error.  I am able to get all of the elements of the desired webpage but when I loop through all of them, I have trouble locating a property that only the elements I am seeking have. I'm looping through the Merriam Webster Unabridged Dictionary which is a paid service so I can't simply link to a sample website but I can provide a picture and a sample of the html code.  In the html code:

```
<h3>Exact matches:</h3>
<ol>
                <li class="selected">
        <a href="platina" data-show-id="0" onclick="return onStandardSearchSelection(this);"><sup>1</sup><b>platina</b> (noun)</a>
    </li>
                <li class="unselected">
        <a href="platina" data-show-id="1" onclick="return onStandardSearchSelection(this);"><sup>2</sup><b>platina</b> (adjective)</a>
    </li>
    </ol>
```

So in the html code above, each website will have a section that says 'exact matches' then you click on a each match, whether it's a noun, adjective, verb etc.  So here there is 'platina' the noun and 'platina' the adjective.  Their xpaths are:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/ol[1]/li[1]/a[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/ol[1]/li[2]/a[1]
```

respectively.  But I cannot figure out for each page how to get the xpath for each object under the header 'exact matches'.